How do i change this icon on the welcome page of vs code?
How do i change the icon of vs code here?Vscode Icon
Now, i want to change this image as i want to customize it, and ive seen people change that icon but i cant find the file location to do that, i have tried to access the file location but cant seem to find the "out" file location that is in the images of people who have done this, can someone please guide me through how to do this?

in what location? embedded in an application? do you know how to edit an icon file? can you recompile an application?

In order to change the workbench logo, you can load your custom CSS using this extension. The instructions to set up are available on the extension's page, then you can create your custom CSS to point to a different logo (in the case where the logo is on your PC) :
.editor-group-watermark>.letterpress {
    background-image:url("C:/Users/MyUserName/Documents/logo.png") !important;
    opacity: 0.75;
    overflow: visible;
    filter: none;
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}

